# SELECT part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a string like that `$TAOVV*NK_LFE_11029_41586` and i want to select only 11029, the number between _. I try with

```
substring([OrderCode],PatIndex('%_[0-9]_%', [OrderCode]),LEN([OrderCode]))
```

but not extract only that number.How i can define the length that change and it's not always of 5 characters as in this example?

Comment: Please only tag the relevant DBMS

Comment: Is it always before the last `_`?

Comment: it's between  the last 2 _

Comment: i not want the last number but the number before.It's between two _

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the substring twice..
Try with this

```
declare @code nvarchar(100)='$TAOVV*NK_LFE_11029_41586'
select substring(substring(@code,PatIndex('%_[0-9]_%', @code)+1,LEN(@code)),1,charindex('_',substring(@code,PatIndex('%_[0-9]_%', @code)+1,LEN(@code)))-1)
```

Comment: it work!!Thank you very much!!

Comment: it is not working with this text: `'$TAOVV*NK_LFE_11029_41586_41111_7474'` , it is retreving also `11029` !!

Comment: This will select the first pattern of `"_[0-9]_"`in the string, not the second last. I don't know if this is a problem for OP.